# Trying to merge, says up to date but it is not

Tags: git

I'm on my master branch, and trying to merge:

```
>git merge feature_branch1
>Already up to date
```

But my feature branch has files that my master branch doesn't.

Why isn't it merge the file into the master branch, and why is it telling me it is already up to date?

Comment: Please show the output of `git show-branch`.

Comment: Are you sure you are on master? `git branch` to check on which branch you are

Comment: @ouah yes I did that, it shows the asterisk by master.

Comment: did you commit the changes on your feature branch? Or did you stash them?

Answer (score 2):

It's telling you it's up to date because there are no commits on feature-branch1 which have not been merged into your current branch. Note that this is commit-wise, not anything about files. (That is, it *is* up to date.) If you've done something wacky to delete the files in question in the merge commit or subsequent commits, Git trusts that you meant to do it, and there you are.

So, start checking things:

- See if the files are just deleted in your work tree, with `git status` or `git diff`.
- Verify that the branch is merged, visually in gitk or with `git branch --contains feature-branch`. (This just confirms what you already know.)
- Verify that one of those files is really in the feature branch and really not in master, using `git show feature-branch:path/to/flie` and `git show master:path/to/file`. Maybe you never actually committed them.
- See what commits touched that path using `git log -- path/to/file`. Maybe you committed the deletion of those files.
- See if you did something dumb in the merge commit - `git show <merge-commit>` should print no diff (a diff indicates changes made *in the merge commit itself*). You can also just inspect the diff in `gitk`. Maybe for some reason you removed those files during merge conflict resolution, and committed a bad merge.

Somewhere along the way, you should find where you got off track.